# Vertically centre align a cropped image in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS style that will take an image and scale it to best fit a letter box shaped div. The overflow will be cropped off. I'm close with this and it currently looks like this:

[image: current appearance]

The original image is

[image: original image]

I'd like to modify this so that the image is centered vertically in the div rather than top aligned. What am I missing here? My html is

```css
.crop {
  width: 670px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.crop img {
  width: 670px;
}
```

```html
<div class='crop'>
  <img src='http://cycle.travel/images/600/amsterdam_ccby_conor_luddy.jpg' />
</div>
```

I can't assume the height of the image to be the same everywhere I use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can position the image relatively and then have the browser bump it upward 50% with `top:-50%;`:

```css
.crop {
  width: 670px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.crop img {
  width: 670px;
  position:relative;
  top:-50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='crop'>
  <img src='http://cycle.travel/images/600/amsterdam_ccby_conor_luddy.jpg' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS `background-position` property. 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

```css
.crop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('http://cycle.travel/images/600/amsterdam_ccby_conor_luddy.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='crop'></div>
```